# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError and types parsing

Tags: java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a dll, which I want to use in my java code.
I declare a function as native and the return type is bool (c).
As I saw in JNI documentation, java 'boolean' should be mapped as 'jboolean' in c code. But the problem is that i don't have the c code, only dll.

My actually problem is UnsatisfiedLinkError, but I have no idea what else can be wrong.

If it is the problem, should i write another c-wrapper?

(I know that this exception was already discussed a lot of times, but I didn't find some useful information according my case)

UPD:
Maybe there are anothere way to use dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an arbitrary DLL directly from Java. You have to declare a native Java method, write the JNI for it, and call the DLL method(s) from the JNI code.